# You have already activated rspec-support 3.0.0.beta1, but your Gemfile requires rspec-support 3.0.0.beta1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems

When I run

```
rspec spec/
```

in my command line, I receive the following error:

> You have already activated `rspec-support 3.0.0.beta1`, but your `Gemfile` requires `rspec-support 3.0.0.beta1`. Using `bundle exec` may solve this. `(Gem::LoadError)`

I tried using `bundle exec` like the error suggests, but to no avail. It's weird that it's telling me that it requires a version that have already activated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try the complete command

```
bundle exec rspec spec/
```

In case this one do not work, try deleting the `Gemfile.lock` file and `bundle install` from scratch. Then retry.

Comment: I suspect he just used the `bundle exec` command, without the `rspec spec/` part.

Comment: I fiddled around with some things in the Gemfile. I removed the '2.0.0.beta.18' after gem 'rspec-rails'. When I run the command with bundle exec, it works. Without, it does not. Sevenseacat is correct, I did initially type everything out, but it still didn't work.Thanks, folks.

Comment: Thank you. I updated the answer to suggest to delete the Gemfile.lock. Sometimes it messes all up.

Comment: Deleting the Gemfile.lock really isn't a good way to go about things either. Unless you've locked down most of the gems in your Gemfile (which most people don't do), you'll likely end up with completely different versions and a whole lot of incompatibilities and pain.

Comment: That's not really a problem with Gemfile.lock but with gems definitions in the Gemfile. To avoid such problems one should really express gem versions to be loaded. Otherwise you'll end up with incompatibilities really soon.

Answer (score 2):

To me, prepending `bundle exec` seems like a workaround rather than a solution to the problem.

I added a `.ruby-gemset` file to my project's root directory (containing an arbitrary gemset name) and that fixed the problem. I believe you could do the following:

```
echo 'my-project-name' > .ruby-gemset
cd ..
cd my-project-directory
gem install bundler
bundle install
rspec spec
```